# Cakephp 2.1 fatal error

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Fatal error: Class 'FacebookInfo' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\cake21\app\Lib\fb.php on line 22

Can someone help me figure this thing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is just what it says: You have not included the file which contains the definition for `class FacebookInfo`.

Make sure you have defined the class above or used `include('filename.php')` which defines `FacebookInfo`.

Comment: @apishcrazy Glad it was helpful. Consider upvoting it and/or marking it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just load you're Lib Class with App::uses()

```
App::uses('FacebookInfo', 'Lib');
```

Be sure that you're file is named equal to your class, in your case FacebookInfo.php

See also: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html